# sqlite database data not loading in android real device

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have created a app it contain sqlite database for list of contacts.application running successfully in emulator it showing list of contacts then i checked with real device.when i check real device everything okay but sqlite database data not loading in real device it showing empty listviews.
Searched solution for this problem.many people suggested that uninstall the app and again install it on the phone.i did it but its not working, again showing empty list

what should i do for db data loading in real device?

Comment: You could connect the real device to ADB and check if the DB file is present at its location within the app in the real device. If it's present, download the DB file to your PC and check if it has data.

Answer (score 0):

If you work on the local, your emulator can get the data from db but real device cannot. To get data for real device, you should open your pc for external devices (maybe you can use wi-fi connection). If you have a hosting or something like that there should be no problem to get data from db.

Answer (score 0):

So you can work directly with SQLite database using SQLite Query function or rawQuery. 
Basically a select will be on the bench and returned a Cursor where you can work with the data using the getInt (int columnIndex), getString (int columnIndex), so on. 
To find the index of the column just use getColumnIndex (String columnName)

Basic example:

```
public class Teste extends Activity {

public Contato carregarContato(String nomeContato){

SQLiteOpenHelper helper = new SQLiteOpenHelper(this, "nomebanco", null, 1) {

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE CONTATO (  " 
        + "    ID INTEGER, " 
        + "    NOME VARCHAR( 100 ), " 
        + "    TELEFONE VARCHAR( 30 ) );");

    }
};


Cursor cursor = helper.getReadableDatabase().query("CONTATO", null, " NOME LIKE '%?%'", new String[]{nomeContato}, null, null, null);

if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    Contato contato = new Contato();

    contato.setCodigo(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID")));
    contato.setNome(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("NOME")));
    contato.setTelefone(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("TELEFONE")));
    return contato;
} else 
    return null;
}

public class Contato {
private int codigo;
private String nome;
private String telefone;
public int getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}
public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}
public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
public String getTelefone() {
    return telefone;
}
public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
    this.telefone = telefone;
}
```

}